# Jquery Codrops Calendario - How to setup background color of each event

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm trying to customize the background of each event on this calendar from Codrops Calendario. (http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/27/calendario-a-flexible-calendar-plugin/)

I can't figure out how the `jquery.calendario.js` parses the variable fron the file `data.js`.

Anyone know how to do that?

This is the structure of `data.js`:

```
var codropsEvents = {
    '05-06-2015' : '<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora perferendis praesentium molestias libero dicta asperiores pariatur dolor in illum, voluptatem eius illo sit odio cumque modi ea ullam commodi, maiores?</span>',
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know there were questions being asked on my repo, or codrops one. But you can add `category` key to the event object in data.js or wherever the data comes from. If suppose for example like Shalaby has a `busy` event your event will be

```
'05-06-2015' : [{
     content: "Lorem ipsum",
     category: "busy"
}]
```

Note: Adding `content` key is mandatory and putting the even objects in a array is mandatory too from v4 onwards to maintain consistency. Also you don't have to add span tags anymore cause calendario will add it for you and if you have an `url` key it will wrap the content with an anchor tag with `href` attribute pointing yo `url`.

So the html code rendered for the above code will be

```
 <div class="fc-calendar-event">
     <span class="calendar-busy">Lorem ipsum</span>
     ....
 </div>
```

The class is now `calendar-busy` and by default it is `calendar-default` if category isn't provided as shown in Shalaby's example. So with this approach your individual events in the lists can have different colors through css but if you want like Shalaby, it is difficult to implement it in Calendario because a date can contain multiple events with different categories, but either way you can do that through CSS using `:has` or `:not` these seem not to haven been implemented but they are the future so look for a work around these don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I understand if its too late and I'm sure there might be a better way but here is how I did it:

assuming that you are using v4 from [deviprsd21's Calendario repo](https://github.com/deviprsd21/Calendario)

in this version, the events are within the days' html markup so for example:

```
<div class="fc-today fc-future fc-content">
  <span class="fc-date">4</span>
  <span class="fc-weekday">Sun</span>
  <div class="fc-calendar-events">
    <div class="fc-calendar-event">
      <span class="calendar-default">Busy</span>
      <time class="fc-allday" datetime="true"></time>
      <time class="fc-starttime" datetime="2015-10-04T00:00:00.000Z"></time>
      <time class="fc-endtime" datetime="2015-10-04T23:59:00.000Z"></time>   
      <note></note>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

my events are passed through json so  in my case "Busy" is a unique status value in my events.
So within the following function:

```
$('#calendar').on('shown.calendar.calendario', function(){
```

I added:

```
    $('.calendar-default').each(function() {
      if ($(this).html() == "Busy"){
        $(this).closest('.fc-content').addClass("busy");
      } else {
        $(this).closest('.fc-content').addClass("available");
      }
    });
```

in the css I added busy and available classes each with a different color and the output was:

[image: Different colors for different events]

Edit: please let me know if you have found a cleaner way of doing it :)

Comment: No, I don't have found another way. I will try yours!! Thanks for help!